# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions. forEach javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am using `forEach` inside a function in javascript and code compilation is getting failed with error `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`. **I am using 2 forEach and error coming for both**. My code is as below

```
const mapRole = (data, worker = false) => {
const byServiceGroup = [];
data?.forEach((obj) => {
const { roleName = '', groupCombination = [] } = obj;
const serviceGroupIds = groupCombination?.find(({ groupName }) => groupName === 
'service_group')
  ?.ids;
serviceGroupIds?.forEach((group) => {
  let path = `/att/${worker ? 'w' : 'en'}/${
    roleName ? roleName + '/' : ''
  }ds`;
  if (group === 'ALL') return; // skipping for 'ALL'
  byServiceGroup.push({
    serviceGroup: group,
    worker: worker,
    path: path,
    userRole: roleName,
  });
});
});
 return byServiceGroup;
};
```

Comment: Which line of the code elicits taht error?

Comment: perhaps your eslint configuration doesn't allow `?.` optional chaining - though, you do use optional chaining in another line at least - what version eslint?

Comment: Yes, I am using optional chaining on other places.

Comment: Well, I can't replicate the error with that code - even when forcing `no-unused-expressions: "error"` - not sure what the answer below is on about :p

Comment: @JaromandaX you are right actually,`?` causing issue even optional chaining working on other placing. Please put it as an answer and I will accept that.

Comment: no idea what the answer is though!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248196/discussion-between-ashwani-panwar-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed `?` before forEach.